# How to use Neo4j Community Edition on GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, neo4j

I'm quite new to GKE and DevOps and maybe I'm misunderstanding the fundamentals of how Kubernetes or cold storage works but is it possible to run Neo4j on GKE without deploying the Marketplace Enterprise Causal Cluster? It seems a bit overkill just to have a graph database in my cluster.

What I'm looking for is a way to maybe run the Neo4j Docker image directly with the correct StorageClaims etc.

If anyone has advice on where to find more info about this it would help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to to GKE, then manually deploying and configuring an app within Kubernetes can be quite tedious; however, it will give you some hands on experience.

If you go to the official "neo4j" website, they have their own operations manual to guide users from simply running neo4j in a docker container to clustering. I have attached the link to their page [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/introduction/).